# Eclipse 2.0.2 and Maven 0.17 Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project and I'm getting this error in Eclipse:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.jar.Manifest.write(java.io.PrintWriter)  pom.xml /rpc-server line
>   1 Maven Configuration Problem

I can to run `mvn clean install` with no problems on command line.
This is just annoying and I'm hoping someone else already tackled this.

Using Eclipse Java EE IDE version 2.0.2.20140224,
with m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties version 0.17.1.201605251832.

Thanks

Comment: I have the some issue. I am running Eclipse Neon (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800 and M2Eclipse 1.7.0.20160603-1933

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem can be solved via

https://otto.takari.io/content/sites/m2e.extras/m2eclipse-mavenarchiver/0.17.2/N/LATEST/

Comment: I can confirm this works, too, though the answer is a bit vague. In Eclipse Neon on Mac, you need to go to Help -> Install New Software; paste the above link in the Work With field of the dialog that pops up; and then install the updated m2e plugin. Eclipse should prompt you to restart Eclipse, and then the error should be gone. The process should be similar for other versions of Eclipse on other OSes; hopefully this fix works there, too!